# Expo client on ios is not working to the QR code

Tags: react-native, expo

I have tried a lot to build a mobile app using expo with react native. Although I want to run the app using npm start command it outputs the QR code. But when I scan it using my expo client app on iphone. My app is not rendering.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I recommend to create an expo account and login in your terminal

```
expo login
```

Then login in your app and your project will appear, no need to scan qr code each time and your builds will be accessible everytime.

Answer (score 16):

Run following in your terminal:

`expo-cli start --tunnel`

Your project will appear in Expo App.

*Both devices must be connected to `the same Wi-Fi` though.*

Comment: the tunnel argument worked for public networks. requires @expo/ngrok dependency

Answer (score 4):

there is a workaround for the QR way of getting things done. Below worked for me.

1. Run the Expo server on an EC2 (or any VM). On AWS i used T2Micro
2. Expose the port 19000
3. go to `www.the-qrcode-generator.com` get QR code for the url: `exp://<public ip of the ec2/ VM>:19000` . Send the QR code to people.
4. This QR code can be scanned by iPhone Camera app which will open Expo app. On Android the Expo QR scanner can scan and download